# Sonar rules to catch logger error outside catch block

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Is there any sonar rules to capture logger error outside the catch block ? I could not find the same in the available rules.

Comment: could you please add a code sample?

Comment: To phrase the comment in a different way, we can't figure out what problem you're describing.  Be explicit about what you're asking for.